# Getting full access to Photos Library on 10.13 or lower

Tags: macos, photosframework

I am trying to get full (read/write) access to the Photos Library - use case is I want to access the library, create/delete albums and move assets into/out of albums, as well as delete them from the library. I've already gone the MLMediaLibrary way, but in that case I can only get read access.

In the new 10.13 API the Photos package has been made available to OSX, however many of the functions are still only available for iOS per the documentation. In particular all findAsset functions are unavailable in OSX. In other words, I cannot find an entry point into the API to get PHAssets! I have tried looking into the MLMedia assets to see if there is a way to migrate the id into the Photos framework, to no avail. Could not find examples *not* relating to iOS either.

Any help appreciated! Ideally looking for a Swift solution, but open to Obj-C as well.

Thanks
E.

Comment: Use AppleScript.

Comment: I might look into Applescript at some point, but right now I'm looking for a Swift/ObjC solution. This is part of a larger application and I am not keen right now in interfacing w/ Applescript

Comment: This page explicitly says support for macOS is included: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624757-fetchassets

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Must be a recent change, it was not the case when the question was asked. At that time I ended up doing a completely roundabout way with Applescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Photos framework is available on macOS only for restricted use cases:

- In macOS 10.11 (El Capitan) and later you can create Photo Editing Extensions. These appear in the Photos app when the user goes to edit a photo — you provide a view controller, and Photos provides you the content of the (single) photo/video to be edited and lets you return edited photo/video content.
- In macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) and later you can also create Photo Project Extensions. These also appear in the Photos app, when the user goes to create a project (like the books, calendars and other physical print products you've been able to order from Apple ever since iPhoto 1.0 many years ago). Photos provides your extension with a list of assets chosen by the user, and access to photo data for those assets, so that you can create your own book, website, coffee mug, or whatever from them.

There's no support for using Photos / PhotosUI (aka PhotoKit) in macOS outside of these use cases. An app linking against Photos framework gets no access (not even read only access) to the user's Photos library.

Comment: thanks! Do you have a link to the documentation stating this so I can follow it when/if something changes?

Comment: >.< It's one of those things you sort of have to read between the lines in [the current docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit) to pick up, and/or piece together between the "availability" notes on those docs and the actual SDK headers in Xcode. [Filing bugs to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) against the frameworks or the docs is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue. I have tried to access Photos library with MLMediaLibrary, but if a photo is stored in iCloud only, you won‘t even see or find it. I have tried to use the type method  **fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options:** to get the Phassets, but the fetch result is always empty because I don‘t know how to get the localidentifiers. So this method is pretty useless. I have asked in Apples developer forum about it but you won‘t get any help from an Apple Engineer there. I have searched for days, but it seems you can‘t access  Photos Library with the Photos framework at the moment.